# How is element width calculated with flex-grow?

Tags: css, flexbox, web-frontend

I am learning CSS and there is a question that I want you to help me solve.

You have an element 'div' that has two children inside it, 'article' and 'aside'.

Suppose the parent 'div' has a width of 900px, the 'article' element has a width of 120px and the 'aside' element has a width of 450px

The CSS looks as follows:

```
    div {
        width: 900px;
        display: flex;
    }
    
    article {
         flex-grow: 2;
         width: 120px;
    }
    
    aside {
        flex-grow: 1;
        width: 450px;
    }
```

Each 'flex-grow: 1' will have a width of:

1. 330px
2. 110px
3. 150px
4. 0 (flex-grow cannot be calculated)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have `330px` of free space (`900 - 450 - 120`). The first element will grow twice than the second one. The total grow factor is `3` (`2+1`) so the first one will take `2/3*330 = 220px` and the second one `1/3*330px = 110px` and we will end with

```
article = 120px + 220px = 340px
aside   = 450px + 110px = 560px
```

Inspect the below code to validate the values:

```css
div {
  width: 900px;
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
}

article {
  flex-grow: 2;
  width: 120px;
  background: red;
}

aside {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 450px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <article></article>
  <aside></aside>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `aside` element with the `flex-grow` factor of `1` will grow by **`110px`** in your scenario.

Here are the rough steps the Flexbox layout algorithm takes to resolve the flexible lengths of the flex items:

**Figure out if the flex items should grow or shrink**

- our flex container is `900px` wide
- the sum of the widths of our flex items is `120px + 450px = 570px`
- there’s remaining free space left (`900px - 570px = 330px`), so our items should grow

**Distribute the remaining free space to the flex items**

- first, we add up the flex grow factors of our flex items: `flex-grow: 2` for `article` and `flex-grow: 1` for `aside` gives us a sum of `3`
- now, we proportionally distribute the remaining space to the flex items using this formula: `flex item grow factor / sum of all flex item grow factors * remaining free space`

  - `aside` gets an extra `110px`, because `1/3 * 330px = 110px`
  - `article` gets an extra `220px`, because `2/3 * 330px = 220px`

```css
div {
  width: 900px;
  display: flex;
}

article {
  flex-grow: 2;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: tomato;
}

aside {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 450px;
  background-color: royalblue;
}

body {
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 3;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <article>
    article grows by 220px
  </article>
  <aside>
    aside grows by 110px
  </aside>
</div>
```